# Not RollingBack in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, transactions

I want to create a transactional method to remove insertions in the database if any errors occur.

My test :
I call it, checkNamespaceAndService.getNamespace is success so OK, but deploiment.setGitCommit is failed for validation reasons. So an exception is thrown.

But in the database, the result of the first method is kept.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public HistoriqueDeploiement saveHistoriqueDeploiementMethod(HistoriqueDeploiementReadingDTO historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO) throws InternalServerErrorException {
        try {       
            Namespace namespace = checkNamespaceAndService.getNamespace(historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getNamespace());
            Service service = checkNamespaceAndService.getServices(historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getService());
    
            HistoriqueDeploiement deploiment = new HistoriqueDeploiement();
            deploiment.setNamespace(namespace);
            deploiment.setService(service);
            deploiment.setGitCommit(historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getGit_commit());
            deploiment.setTagVersion(historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getTag_version());
            deploiment.setActionBy(historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getAction_by());
            
            historiqueDeploiementRepository.save(deploiment);
            log.info("[Historisation] Ajout réalisé pour -> Namespace : " + historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getNamespace() + " -> Service : " + historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getService() + " -> Tag : " + historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getGit_commit());
            return deploiment;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("[Historisation] Ajout réalisé pour -> Namespace : " + historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getNamespace() + " -> Service : " + historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getService() + " -> Tag : " + historiqueDeploiementReadingDTO.getGit_commit());
            log.warn("[@Transactional] Rollback exécuté");
            throw new InternalServerErrorException("Une erreur est survenue lors de l'ajout de l'historique de déploiement");
        }
    }
```

On my main class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement // Added for testing, because without it does not work too.
```

I hope someone know why the rollback is not called.

Comment: Are you calling the save method from same class or different class?

Comment: historiqueDeploiementRepository.save(deploiment); is in the transactional

I call : saveHistoriqueDeploiementMethod from the controller